# Locked doors during power failure

Tags: power-windows

I have a Lexus CT200H and a Mercedes C200. If there is a power failure when driving, will the car doors unlock automatically?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about vehicle maintenance or repairs.

Comment: I think it's actually a valid, and answerable question - from a maintenance perspective, it is useful to know all the basic functions of the car.

Comment: What does your vehicle's manual say?

Comment: @RoryAlsop If this is a valid question, is it valid if we post the same question for every make / model combo of vehicle? This can be a real slippery slope if we allow curiosity based questions for any make / model combination out there.

Comment: hmmm - good point @cory - it is a 'read the manual' question I guess

Answer (score 1):

Mercedes and BMW both definitely have a safety system which will, in the event of a collision which will unlock the doors.  This can be triggered by driving over a pot-hole at speed.  This is to prevent the scenario whereby someone is trapped by the vehicle door locks in an accident.

Saab have a safeguard on their cars that, when the battery charge drops to a certain point and the car is parked, they unlock their doors.  This is to prevent the scenario whereby the battery has run out and the car is locked, therefore the car cannot be opened and the battery recharged.

I appreciate that neither of these scenarios matches your question.  I would answer your question with a question; what do you mean by power failure whilst driving?  If you mean that, during operation of the vehicle, the electrical system fails suddenly and completely, I would quite honestly doubt that any vehicle with electromagnetically, electromagnetically or electronically controlled central locking out unlock it's doors because in a sudden, catastrophic and total power failure, there would be no electrical power available to operate the locks, or to even trigger the signal to perform the unlock operation.  So, do you mean that the battery charge drops below a certain point or do you mean sudden and complete power loss?

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful responses. I did mean both scenarios i.e. if the battery charge drops below a certain point, as well as in the event of a catastrophic power failure.

Comment: I envisaged being trapped in the car on a dark wet or icy night, and having a power outage, and wondered what I should do.